# Delay React Hook useLayoutEffect until useEffect is done?

Tags: reactjs, amcharts, use-effect

I have a component in which I use the hook `useEffect` to retrieve data from an API. I want to display the data in a chart using AMCharts. My problem is that I need to use the hook `useLayoutEffect` to create the chart and the chart is based on the data retrieved with `useEffect`... When my chart is rendered, I don't have the data yet and my chart is empty. How can I delay the `useLayoutEffect` until the data is retrieved ?

I use `useEffect` a lot in my app to retrieve data and display the info I need. I tried to do both (retrieve data and create the chart) in the hook `useEffect` or in the `useLayoutEffect` but it does not work. I cannot use a condition before using `useLayoutEffect`, tried it too...

```
const AmChart = (props) => {
    const chartRef = useRef(null);

    const [data,setData] = useState([]);
    const [startDate,setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
    const [endDate,setEndDate] = useState(new Date());

    useEffect(() => {
        let from = startDate.getFullYear().toString() + ('0' + (startDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + ('0' + startDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
        let to = endDate.getFullYear().toString() + ('0' + (endDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + ('0' + endDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
        dataService.getData(from,to)
            .then(response => {
                setData(response.data);
            });
    },[]);

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        let x = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
        // ... creation of the chart
        chart.data = data;
        // ... creation of the chart
        chart.current = x;

        return () => {
          x.dispose();
        };
    }, []);

    return (
      <div id="chartdiv" style={{ width: "100%", height: "500px" }}></div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `useLayoutEffect` to create your graph ? Can't you just create it in a separate method, and call this method as the return value of your useEffect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add 'data' to the list of dependencies for useEffect. For more info please read this article: [Docs on useEffect conditional firing](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect)

Answer (score 0):

If you need your hook does the work when data is changed, add data state into an array of dependencies.

```
useLayoutEffect(()=>{}, [data])
```